# Perl find min value with custom compare funciton

Tags: perl, min

Is there a way to find minimum value in array with custom compare function except sort it and take first item?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create one using `reduce` from `List::Util`.

```
use List::Util qw/reduce/;
$min = reduce { $a < $b ? $a : $b } 1..10 # regular minimum
```

If you want to compare strings, for example, replace `<` with `le` (although `List::Util` also exports `minstr`).

Comment: `List::Util` has `min` function too, why not to use it directly?

Comment: @wk: The OP asks for a way to customize the comparison function.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want higher order functions, perhaps, switch to a functional language?

But fear not, you can simulate it in perl, or choose the easy solution:

```
 my $min = shift @yourlist; # or $yourlist[0] if the list must remain intact      
 # assuming that your compare function is named "lower"
 map { $min = $_ if lower($_, min) } @yourlist;
```

Comment: Perl *is* a functional language. Not a pure one, of course, but it has [most of the defining features](http://perlalchemy.blogspot.com/2009/11/what-are-features-that-perl-shares-with.html).

Comment: Why would you use a map instead of a for loop?

Comment: @daxim - I know, thought, syntactic issues and performance make it almost impossible to use it as such. The biggest obstacle, of course, is it's lack of a sound type system - although this is no requirement for functional languages, it certainly makes functional programming really rock. Don't take this as anti Perl advocacy - I am myself an old perl hacker, yet one who sees that sometimes there are better ways to do certain things.

Comment: @Tim: There's more than 1 way to do it, you know :)  - in this particular case, it looked to me as though a next to functional solution was natural. Or perhaps I have done too much Haskell lately, so that imperative constructs like loops don't come to my mind.

Comment: @Ingo: Of course a `map` works just as well, but I see no reason that a higher-order function would be needed or even make things simpler in this situation. The use of `map` seemed to share origin with your desire to use Haskell instead.

Comment: @Tim You are right, but map is, of course, a higher order function. As well as the reduce (aka fold) in your solution, which is indeed the best, so you get +1 from me.